# Change of variables in Einstein summation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

This should be trivial, but I am not able to work it out. How is the following equality true?

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial p^2} = \frac{1}{2p^2}p^\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial p^\mu} \,,$$

where $ p^2 = p^\mu p_\mu$.

Basically, it involves calculating the partial derivative $$\frac{\partial p^\mu}{\partial p^2} = \Big(\frac{\partial p^2}{\partial p^\mu}\Big)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}(p^\mu)^{-1} \,,$$ and showing that $$ \boxed{\color{blue}{(p^\mu)^{-1} = \frac{p^\mu}{p^2}}} \,. $$

I am not sure if what I have done above is rigorous at all.

NOTE: I am not sure if the argument about multiplying and dividing $(p^\mu)^{-1}$ by a factor of $p^\mu$ works rigorously because there would be an implicit summation in the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is is
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial p^\mu}=\frac{\partial p^2}{\partial p^\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial p^2}.
$$
Then,
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial p^\mu}=2p_\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial p^2}.
$$
Now, multiply by $p^\mu$ both side and you get
$$
   p^\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial p^\mu}=2p^2\frac{\partial}{\partial p^2}
$$
and you are done.